# LINQ Dinâmico a partir de DTO - Filtragem por DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, filtro, linq-to-entities

Estou tentando montar um filtro dinâmico a partir de um objeto DTOFiltro que eu recebo preenchido através da View. O meu problema é, quando eu tento filtrar os resultados que serão mostrados na tela por MesAno, eu não consigo fazer um tratamento adequado dos dados para que o LinqToEntities consiga interpretar a string de where que é montada... Tentei coletar alguns exemplos do código para exemplificar melhor o problema e deixei umas das soluções já testadas que não deram certo.

O código é parte de uma aplicação em MVC5 que estou desenvolvendo. E eu não sei nem como pesquisar uma solução para o meu problema...

Da maneira que o código está no momento, eu consigo passar as informações da camada de serviços para o repositório e fazer a consulta no linqtoentities, mas o mesmo não retorna resultados, embora eu tenha certeza que há dados no banco que supostamente estariam de acordo com a query...

Qual a maneira ideal de tratar este caso? Há alguma forma mais fácil de se montar uma string dinâmica para o .Where do objeto do banco de dados?

```
    //MeuModeloService.cs
    public class MeuModeloService : IService<DTOFiltroMeuModelo, DTOMeuModelo>
    {
        private IRepositorioMeuModelo _repoMeuModelo;
        //...
        public MeuModeloService()
        {
            _repoMeuModelo = new RepositorioMeuModelo();
            //...
        }
        //...
        //Métodos de serviço abaixo
        //...
    }
    public string MontaWhere(DTOFiltroMeuModelo filtros)
    {
        string filtroCustomizado = " 1 = 1 ";

        if (filtros.IdPerfil > 0)
            filtroCustomizado += " and IdPerfilCCEE = " + filtros.IdPerfil;

        if (filtros.IdAgente > 0 && filtros.IdPerfil == 0)
        {
            List<int> lstIdPerfil = _repoPerfil.Listar("IdAgente = " + filtros.IdAgente).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
            foreach (var idPerfil in lstIdPerfil)
            {
                filtroCustomizado += " and IdPerfilCCEE = " + idPerfil + "";
            }
        }

        if (filtros.IdCliente > 0)
            filtroCustomizado += " and IdCliente = " + filtros.IdCliente + "";

        if (filtros.IdUnidade > 0)
            filtroCustomizado += " and IdUnidade = " + filtros.IdUnidade + "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filtros.MesAno))
        {
            var MesAnoSplit = filtros.MesAno.Split('/');
            filtroCustomizado += " and string.Equals((MesAno.Year.ToString() + \"-\" + MesAno.Month.ToString() + \"-\" + MesAno.Day.ToString()), \"" + MesAnoSplit[2] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[1] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[0] + "\")";

            //Outras abordagens de solução
            //filtroCustomizado += " and MesAno.ToString(\"yyyy-mm-dd\") = \"" + MesAnoSplit[2] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[1] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[0] + "\"";
            //filtroCustomizado += " and MesAno = DateTime.Parse(\"" + MesAnoSplit[0] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[1] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[2] + "\")";
            //filtroCustomizado += " and MesAno = DateTime.ParseExact(\"" + MesAnoSplit[2] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[1] + "-" + MesAnoSplit[0] + "\", \"YYYY-MM-DD\", new CultureInfo(\"en-US\"))";
        }

        return filtroCustomizado;
    }


    public int BuscarNumeroTotalDeItens(DTOFiltroMeuModelo filtros)
    {
        return _repoMeuModelo.NumTotalLista(MontaWhere(filtros));
    }

    public List<DTOMeuModelo> ListarComPaginacao(DTOFiltroMeuModelo filtros)
    {
        DTOPaginacao paginacao = filtros.Paginacao;

        string where = string.Empty;
        int itemPorPag = paginacao.ItemPorPagina;
        int limiteInicial = 0;
        int limiteFinal = itemPorPag;
        string ordem = filtros.Ordem + " " + filtros.TipoOrdem;

        where = MontaWhere(filtros);

        if (paginacao.Pagina > 0)
        {
            limiteInicial = (paginacao.Pagina - 1) * itemPorPag;
        }

        List<DTOMeuModelo> listagem = new List<DTOMeuModelo>();

        foreach (var item in _repoMeuModelo.Listar(where, limiteInicial, limiteFinal, ordem))
        {
            var dtoModelo = new DTOMeuModelo(item, false);
            listagem.Add(dtoModelo);
        }

        return listagem;
    }


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //DTOFiltroMeuModelo.cs

    public class DTOFiltroMeuModelo
    {
        [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Perfil")]
        public int IdPerfil { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Agente")]
        public int IdAgente { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Unidade")]
        public int IdUnidade { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mês/Ano")]
        public string MesAno { get; set; }
        public string Ordem { get; set; }
        public string TipoOrdem { get; set; }
        public DTOPaginacao Paginacao { get; set; }

        public DTOFiltroMeuModelo()
        {
            this.Ordem = "Id";
            this.TipoOrdem = "DESC";
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //RepositorioMeuModelo.cs

    public IEnumerable<ModeloEDMX> Listar(string filtroCustomizado, int limiteInicial, int limiteFinal, string orderBy)
    {
        IQueryable<ModeloEDMX> queryFiltro = BancoDeDados.ModeloEDMX.AsQueryable();

        if (filtroCustomizado != "")
            queryFiltro = queryFiltro.Where(filtroCustomizado);

        var listaRegistroExcluido = from registros in BancoDeDados.SmartRegistro
                          join entidade in BancoDeDados.ModeloEDMX on registros.IdRegistro equals entidade.Id into merge
                          from filtrado in merge.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where registros.Tabela == "ModeloEDMX" && (registros.Status == 6 || registros.Status == 12)
                          select filtrado;

        var queryResult = queryFiltro.Except(listaRegistroExcluido);

        queryResult = MontaQueryLimites(queryResult, limiteInicial, limiteFinal, orderBy);

        var lstDados = queryResult.ToList();

        return lstDados as IEnumerable<ModeloEDMX>;
    }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta tá bastante confusa. Tente ser [edit] e dar uma melhorada. Sugiro também fazer um resumão no início, sucintamente dizendo: 1. O que você pretende fazer? 2. O que deu errado e como deu errado?

Comment: Já pensou em ao invés de montar uma string para retornar na função de montar o where, retornar já um IQueryable<ModeloEDMX>? aí vc passa como parametro, além do filtro, o proprio IQueryable<ModeloEDMX>. Aí vc filtra ele dentro da função onde for necessário, utilizando o próprio linq evitando strings mágicas, e retorna o IQueryable<ModeloEDMX> já com os devidos filtros. Entendeu?

Comment: @LeandroSimões Pensei sim, o meu problema pra esse caso é que a maneira como foi estruturado o sistema dita que os serviços não enxergam os modelos de banco, mas somente o repositório e este sim, tem como acessar e manipular objetos de banco.